# Multiple linear regression with dummy variables. Assumptions of t-test

Tags: regression, linear

I am running a regression model with multiple variables. One of the variables is a dummy and the rest are continuous.

When i get the regression output (t value and P>t) i am wondering what the underlying assumptions of this test is, when the variable is a dummy? i have read that the variable should be normally distributed but how can this be true when the variable is a dummy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The t-test is on the **coefficient** of the dummy variable, so the fact that the variable is not normally distributed does not present any problem. Also, the assumption of the linear regression is that the error term normally distributed, not the variable itself.

Comment: Hi.. So the underlying assumption of the t-test on the coefficient for the dummy is that the error term is normally distributed?

Comment: i read this in an econometrics book "The theoretical underpinnings of this procedure are that the OLS estimator has a large-sample normal distribution that,
under the null hypothesis, has as its mean the hypothesized true value and that
the variance of this distribution can be estimated consistently"

Comment: This is an assumption of OLS, the normality of the distribution of the error terms ensures that you can rely on the results of the t-test on the coefficients of the variables. The quote you added talks about the normality of errors, not individual independent variables.